# How to differentiate two websites with different URLs but same IP address?

Tags: url, iis, dns

I have two websites hosted on the same server via IIS. The two websites thus have the same IP address and use the different ports. And this is how we differentiate the two.

We are in the process of DNS mapping the two URLs, but the team that handles this, says that it cannot incorporate the port number in the URLs.

Is there way from IIS to identify the particular website from the URL itself and direct it to the same?

UPDATE: I tried adding new IP address, but the newly added address doesn't show up in IIS site bindings.

Comment: This should help you - http://serverfault.com/questions/74362/how-to-use-dns-hostnames-or-other-ways-to-resolve-to-a-specific-ipport

Comment: This one, as well - http://forums.iis.net/t/1195824.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind multiple sites with same IP address & Port.
But you need to configure host header in site binding.
Refer this link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/06/18/bind-multiple-sites-on-same-ip-address-and-port-in-ssl.aspx

hope this will help

Comment: This will change the URLs of the applications. Something that I cannot do. It is not up-to me to make that decision, and it will most probably not be allowed.

Comment: @Abhid It should not change the URL's, but as you have not given us examples of what your URLs are it will be hard to help you further.

Comment: Thanks Shankar, Host Headers solved our issue. And +1 for Dijkgraaf . That is correct, it did not change urls.